# Webbrowser click on link with OnClick attribute

Tags: c#, onclick, click, webbrowser-control

Let's say that I've got the following HTML:

```
<div id="active_server">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nlp1');">
                <span class="world_button_active">Server NL P1</span>
            </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nlp2');">
                <span class="world_button_active">Server NL P2</span>
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now let's say that i want to simulate an click on server NL P2. I know that I've got to get the HTML. so first i get the div like this:

```
HtmlElement active_server = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("active_server").GetElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

But then is my question as follow:

How do i loop through the elements and search in the `Onclick` wich link I've got to click ( note, the onclick's are variable, so i can't do an index and click or something like that. I really need to compare the onclick or the text in the span)

I'm very new to this type of programming.

**EDIT 1**
I don't really know on what place the element is because it can change ( sometimes there are more servers, and i've got to find the right server...)

**EDIT 2**

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="active_server">
    <p class="pseudo-heading">Op welke wereld wil je je aanmelden?</p>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nl33');">
        <span class="world_button_active">Wereld 33</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nlp1');">
        <span class="world_button_active">Casual</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nl34');">
        <span class="world_button_inactive">Wereld 34</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <p class="pseudo-heading" id="show_all_server">
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#show_all_server').hide();$('#inactive_server_list').show();return false">Toon alle werelden</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess: you're trying to find what `A` link to click by the text, contained in the inner `SPAN` of that link.

Try this:

```
HtmlElement active_server = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("active_server").GetElementsByTagName("div")[0];
HtmlElement link = null;
if (FindLinkToClick(active_server, "Server NL P1", ref link)
{
  link.InvokeMember("click", null);
}

// FindLinkToClick

bool FindLinkToClick(HtmlElement root, string text, ref HtmlElement found)
{
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        var element = (HtmlElement)child;
        if (element.InnerText == text) 
        {
            found = element.Parent;
            return true;
        }
        if (FindLinkToClick(element, text, ref found))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

If you're sure the string you're looking for (e.g, "Server NL P1") is unique, you can just use `webBrowser1.WB.Document.Body` as the `root` for search:

```
HtmlElement link = null;
if (FindLinkToClick(webBrowser1.WB.Document.Body, "Server NL P1", ref link))
{
  link.InvokeMember("click", null);
}
```

**[EDITED]**

I just tested it with the below HTML and it works. Note `<a href="#" onclick="alert('clicked!')">`, I do see that "clicked!" alert.

```
<div id="active_server">
    <p class="pseudo-heading">Op welke wereld wil je je aanmelden?</p>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" onclick="alert('clicked!')">
        <span class="world_button_active">Wereld 33</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nlp1');">
        <span class="world_button_active">Casual</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_nl34');">
        <span class="world_button_inactive">Wereld 34</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call it like this:

```
HtmlElement link = null;
if (FindLinkToClick(this.webBrowser1.Document.Body, "Wereld 33", ref link))
  link.InvokeMember("click", null);
```

**[UPDATE]**

The code works unmodified with the link your provided. Maybe, you need to make sure the document is fully loaded, like this:

```
bool _loaded = false;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.WB.DocumentCompleted += WB_DocumentCompleted;
}

void WB_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_loaded)
        return;
    _loaded = true;

    HtmlElement link = null;
    if (FindLinkToClick(this.WB.Document.Body, "Wereld 33", ref link))
    {
      link.InvokeMember("click", null);
    }
}

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WB.Navigate(@"http://scriptsenprogs.nl/twmc.html");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks good... But i get an object refrence error ( `active_server` is `null`... ) The only thing i can come up with is that the div is generated with JScript after the username / password happaning... Does that make an problem???

-btw-  thanks for thinking / comming with an answer :D

Comment: No problem, I've updated the answer. Can you confirm that a string like "Server NL P1" is actually what you want to search the link with?

Comment: Well... something weird is going on... I'm still getting the object refrence error, but now on the `click` line. I've inserted some messageboxes at the `findlinktoclick` function, but they don't popup. So it doesn't return true, but still try's to click...

Also, i've updated my question with the exact html. I'm trying ( just for testing, later al the other must be able to ) `Wereld 33`... But that doesn't work...

Comment: Works for me, check the answer for an update. Try it with the same HTML, copy from here.

Comment: Alright, i've done what you've said and i get an link found at this part of your script `if (FindLinkToClick(element, text, ref found))
                    return true;` But i still get an object error... The link to the test site ( of the code you provided ) is here: [link](http://scriptsenprogs.nl/twmc.html)

Comment: The code works unmodified with the link your provided. Maybe, you need to make sure the document is fully loaded before doing anything with it? I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Well, i've tryed it again, but it still isn't working. I'm gonna clean the code and get back to you when i'm done. Thanks anyway for taking the time and trying to help me ;)

Comment: No problem, this is as far as I could help with it anyway, based on your input. We can't turn this into interactive debugging session. Hope I gave you a good staring point.

Comment: Yeeah, i gues you're right... I've cleaned up but still the `null` problem... I will bang my head on the wall tomorow and when i find the answer i will post it so that others are lucky mayby. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days ( just in case... ) But i think that the bounty will go to you ;)

Thanks anyway and have a nice ( coding )  day

Comment: BTW, i've tested it in an clean form and there it's working. So i think it's some code that's messing with it. Thank you so very much for the help :D

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out for you :) Note, that code really relies upon: 1) the text in the SPAN is unique, 2) the SPAN is a direct child of the A element.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup ;) As far as i know will that not be an problem. And if it will be i think that i can cover that problem up right now ( thanks to you and your code ;P )

Answer (score 2):

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    HtmlElement active_server = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("active_server").GetElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var a = active_server.GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    a.InvokeMember("click", null);
};
```

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't clear. I don't really know on what place the element is because it can change ( sometimes there are more servers, and i've got to find the right server...) So that won't work on the specific problem ( find the right link to click ). But thanks anyway ;)