# how to click a link in java web page by (herf , ID , or any way ) in c# browser

Tags: c#, javascript, hyperlink, click, browser

i have my c# browser , in my program when the URL change to some value I want the program to click on  specific link in a list of links .

this is the code of the link :

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>       
    <td class="goTo" id="goToAdventure344183">
      <a class="gotoAdventure arrow" href="start_adventure.php?from=list&amp;kid=344183">إلى المغامرة</a>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the class id :"goToAdventure344183" changes by time to this id   "goToAdventure*******"

||| only the stars changes  |||

I wonder if there is a way to to it  , if you can click it byclassname or some thing else
and where shold i but the code in the rbowser or button or ...

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176871/webbrowser-click-on-link-with-onclick-attribute) asked and answered.

Comment: not a similar bro 
in my page the id changes and the link disappear after the click and replaced with the next link in the table but the name of it stay itself
that question mot like mine

Answer (score 0):

If id `goToAdventure***` is always set for `TD` tag you can try this:(else change this code :D)

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\"><tbody>     <td class=\"goTo\" id=\"goToAdventure344183\"><a class=\"gotoAdventure arrow\" href=\"start_adventure.php?from=list&amp;kid=344183\">إلى المغامرة</a></td> </tbody></table></body></html>";
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = webBrowser1.Document.Body.Children;
            foreach (var item in  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td"))
            {
                //<TD> tag id contain goToAdventure
                if ((item as HtmlElement).Id.Contains("goToAdventure"))
                {
                    //Add <A> tag
                    foreach (var taga in (item as HtmlElement).GetElementsByTagName("a"))
                    {
                        webBrowser1.Navigate((taga as HtmlElement).GetAttribute("href"));
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```